# Google spreadsheet creating unique IDs from informations in different columns

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create unique ID's for every items in a Google spreadsheet. This ID has to reflect informations contained in 2 columns. I made a simpler version of my data and joined it as an image [WhereImAt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXRFb.png). As you can see in the first column, I want people to be able to identify the "city", the "type" for each item in the spreadsheet and a number which make the entry unique.

The actual spreadsheet as more than 2k items in it. The column "city" has 19 possible entries and the "type" has 12.

For the moment the only formulas I can think of is "If()", but with so many variables, it looks impossible or way too complex. I'm sure there is something more efficient...

Can anyone think of a better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Cities will probably not all start with a unique character, you would need a table to look up the code for the city.  Since you have a limited number of Cities and Types, you can use a table for each to validate the entries and look up the code.  Assuming a table (sheet/tab) for each you could have a sheet called City and one called Type.  City has the City Names listed in column A, starting at A2, and the associated Code in column B.  Type has the Type listed in column A starting at cell A2, and the associated Code in column B.  Both sheets use row 1 as a Header row.

So in your sheet, in cell B2, place this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE( VLOOKUP(C2, City!A2:B, 2, FALSE), "_", VLOOKUP(D2, Type!A2:B, 2, FALSE))
```

It will look up the City Name and the Type, returning the Code for each, and making a string which is CityCode_TypeCode.

Since you have many rows of data, you do not want to copy this formula for every row.  This is where ARRAYFORMULA comes in.  Unfortunately we cannot use CONCATENATE in an ARRAYFORMULA function, but there is an easy way around that.  The more difficult part is using VLOOKUP, but with the trick used here, we can make that work.  We will combine the strings using & and add an array to the third item of the VLOOKUP to get these to work.  Last, I will use a little trick to place this in row 1 and still apply a header.  For your Column B, you would place this in B1, and make sure the rest of the column is empty:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(C1:C) = 1, "ID", IF(ISBLANK(C1:C),, VLOOKUP(C1:C, City!A2:B, 2 * SIGN( ROW( C1:C ) ), FALSE) & "_" & VLOOKUP(D1:D, Type!A2:B, 2 * SIGN( ROW( D1:D ) ), FALSE))))
```

This only gets us to where you are currently with only one formula.  To get to teh last step, I need assume the data will not be sorted, have rows inserted or deleted, etc.  Is this one rule can be followed, the item in row 3 will ALWAYS be in row 3, we can get you to the last step using the Row Number by adding
TEXT(ROW(A1:A)-1, "0000)
to the mix to get a 4 digit number representing 1 less than the row so that our numbers start at 0001  So in your file, in cell A1, place this with nothing in the rest of the column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(C1:C) = 1, "ID", IF(ISBLANK(C1:C),, VLOOKUP(C1:C, City!A2:B, 2 * SIGN( ROW( C1:C ) ), FALSE) & "_" & VLOOKUP(D1:D, Type!A2:B, 2 * SIGN( ROW( D1:D ) ), FALSE) & "_" & TEXT(ROW(A1:A)-1, "0000"))))
```